# pip Error: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, bash, installation, pip

Here's a sample from my console:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ Ryan$ pip
-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What does this error mean and how do I fix it? It has prevented me from downloading new things via pip install!

Comment: You seem to have `pip` installed, but not `python`. The error says that it could not find the python executable. Have you tried a `which python` to see if and where python has been installed?

Comment: I've been using Python 3 for TensorFlow for quite some time now (which I installed using pip among many other libraries), and I wanted a better way to display images than MatPlotLib. But I must have done something wrong in the console while I was installing it because now I can't get it to work anymore! Python still runs fine and all the libraries I installed still work, it just doesn't let me install new ones anymore. I tried uninstalling pip, but pip uninstall pip doesn't work because pip is broken!

Answer (score 4):

You could try to execute pip via a python version you know works on your system.

Something like:

```
/path/to/python /path/to/pip
```

You could use:

```
which python
which pip
```

to find out the relevant paths.